# how can i insert into? my error is no value given for one more required parameters

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

my error is no value given for one more required parameters.
my fields `new,rev1,rev2,rev3,rev4,rev5` i need to convert to `date`.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [sheet] ([empno],[empname],[projectname],[sheetno],[title],[new],[rev1],[rev2],[rev3],[rev4],[rev5) VALUES (empno ='" _
                 & txtempno.Text & "',empname ='" & txtemp1.Text _
                 & "',projectname = '" & Txtpro.Text & "',sheetno = '" _
                 & txtdrawing.Text & "',title = '" & txtdesc.Text _
                 & "', _
                 new = CDate('" & date1txt.Text & "'), _
                 rev1 = CDate('" & date2txt.Text & "'), _
                 rev2 = CDate('" & date3txt.Text & "'), _
                 rev3 = CDate('" & date4txt.Text & "'),_
                 rev4 = CDate('" & date5txt.Text & "'), _
                 rev5 = CDate('" & date6txt.Text & "'))"
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all look at this line

```
[rev4],[rev5)
```

`]` is missing in `[rev5]`.

Second thing is that you don't need to assign parameter name here

```
",empname ='" & txtemp1.Text & "'"
```

it is better to create parameterized query instead of concatinating string. hackers can easily inject the sql injection in your query.

```
 Values(@empno, @empname,...)
or 
 Values(?, ?,...)
```